# Concatenate integers in calculator app in java

Tags: java

So I am working with a calculator application in java, and I need to write the heart of the code.

I am writing a class that implements an interface, and in my `addDigit(int digit)` method I need it to display the concatenation of the two integers that the user presses on the program.

I have done some research and am finding things like `value = "" + digit * digit;` or something along these lines, but nothing seems to be working.

```
public class BasicAccumulator implements Accumulator {

    private int digit;
    private int value;

    public void BasicAccumulator(int digit, int value)
    {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addDigit(int digit)
    {
        value = digit + "" digit;
    }

    public void plus()
    {
        value = digit + digit;
    }

    public void minus()
    {
        value = digit - digit;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public int displayValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thank you I am new to this sorry.

Comment: @ScottHunter Read the description of the homework tag.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
public void addDigit(int digit)
{
    value = value * 10 + digit;
}
```

or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Wow that worked! Could you please explain why I have to * 10?

Comment: To add a digit to the right of a number you will have to shift the rest of the digits one step to the left, which is done by multiplying by 10. Then, add the new digit to your new value to set the new right-most digit.

Comment: @EricSage: I see that you were helped by an answer to your last question too. Dont forget this (from the faq): _When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer._

Comment: Would anyone mind explaining the plus() method to me? I am confused why doesn't value = value + digit work?

Comment: @EricSage: It's not really clear what you expect from the `plus()` method. If you have a more specific problem implementing it, post a new question about it, but give it a try yourself first so you can explain where you got stuck (if you do).

Comment: Sorry about that Keppil,  the plus() method is just taking the value entered(first punched in) and adding it to another value entered by the user after hitting the + button.  Just like a calculator.  I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to want to work.  I will keep testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addDigit(int digit)
{
    value = (this.digit + "")+ digit;
}
```